# I want to make heartbeat and distributed lock for 2 nodes, what should be took into consideration?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, locking, high-availability

I want to make heartbeat and distributed lock for 2 nodes, just for 2 nodes.
Unlike Zookeeper or Hazelcast, I think it should be very simple.

But I'm not sure if it's really simple, or if some important aspects are missed on the problem, or is there any advanced solution on it.

Please help review the following description for heartbeat and lock, any suggestion/comments are welcome. Thank you.

1. To make heartbeat, node A send packet to node B every second, vise versa. Node A leave will be detected if node B hasn't receive the packet for certain seconds.
2. To make distributed exclusive lock, node A send lock request packet to node B, and node B send ack back, then node A will have the lock; node B may send rejection back, then node A cann't get the lock; or node B is unreachable or request timeout, node A will have the lock.
3. Brain-split could not be avoid because there's only 2 node

BTW: It's not limited to Java language.

Comment: What language or architecture are we talking about here?  Please add better tags.

Comment: Hi @Gray, I add "java" tag, but I think it's not limited to certain language. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to me to be two phase locking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_phase_locking